# Friend function wont work due to undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, friend

This is the Foo.hpp

```
#ifndef Foo_hpp
#define Foo_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include "Bar.hpp"

class Bar;

class Foo
{
private:
   int z;
public:
   void addY(Bar &x);
};
#endif /* Foo_hpp */
```

This is the Bar.hpp

```
#ifndef Bar_hpp
#define Bar_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include "Foo.hpp"

class Bar
{
private:
    int y;
public:
    friend void Foo::addY(Bar&);//use of undeclared identifier 'Foo'
};
#endif /* Bar_hpp */
```

I dont even know why it keeps giving me this error, I try to work on it and try to see if I misspell or mistype anything. I even try to rewrite everything form scratch and still come up with the same error.

Comment: Remove `#include "Bar.hpp"`. You don't need it. (It looks like you tried to fix a circular dependency with a forward declaration, but that's not enough.)

Comment: @molbdnilo wow that actually work, but why thou can you explain it?

Comment: Because you got rid of the definition of `Bar`, which would need the definition of `Foo`, wihch doesn't exist at that point. (Remember that `#include "file"` literally only means "insert the contents of 'file' here".)

Comment: Unrelated: `#include <cstdio>` instead of `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: @molbdnilo ma thank you for the help I almost gave up with this thing.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Why thou, is there any significant different of using the <cstdio> instead of <stdio.h>?

Comment: @prayogayoga  `cstdio` is the c++ equivalent of the c header `stdio.h`.

Comment: What @StefanKssmr said - and some implementations actually puts the content in the `std` namespace only - which is nice.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Oh I see well thank you